# I am using angular 6.1.0 angular-cli 7 primeng 7 : getting error as "Initializers are not allowed in ambient context"

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/primeng/components/picklist/picklist.d.ts(65,28): error
>   TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>   node_modules/primeng/components/picklist/picklist.d.ts(66,28): error
>   TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

I have checked primeng package

```
primeng/components/picklist/picklist.d.ts
line number 65
line number 66

readonly SOURCE_LIST = -1;
readonly TARGET_LIST = 1;
```

> Error :   Initializers are not allowed in ambient context because of
>   above variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PrimeNG 7.x requires Angular 7.

Please always make sure major version of PrimeNG matches the major version of
Angular like PrimeNG 6.x with Angular 6.x.

Angular like PrimeNG 7.x with Angular 7.x.

I was also facing the same problem, I just upgrade angular version 6 to Angular 7.
It fixed my all issue related to prime ng.

> For upgrade form angular 6 to 7 just flow the angular official website
>   [Link](https://update.angular.io/)